# Most intuitive way to indicate clickable elements on GUI across the program

Tags: interactive-ui

There are several common ways to indicate that a GUI label is clickable:

Set hyperlink style (underline and blue) Cons: this steals attention and becomes a distraction for those familiar with a program.

Grey-out inactive elements.  Works for checkboxes, but isn't suitable for text.

Add tooltips - user will hover over elements and learn what is clickable. Cons: user still might miss an element and the upfront cost (creating tooltips for all elements) is high.

Change background of all active elements if a hotkey is pressed. Cons: user must be fairly familiar with the program in order to know about this hotkey.

Show tutorial (similar to one on Stackexchange). Works for introduction of basic concepts. Cons: tutorial can only show most important functions because a user wouldn't watch a lengthy video. Besides it doesn't help when user is working with a program.

What is the most intuitive and non-invasive way to present active elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is deciding how you will make a distinction between interactive and noninteractive elements.

**Noninteractive** elements should:

- look consistent and relatively uninteresting
- have only one state
- be a plain color

**Interactive** elements should:

- command the user's attention
- have an active, hover, and disabled state
- be a different color than its surroundings

Saying that a blue, underlined link is bad because it's a "distraction" sounds kinda funny to me. The alternative is using a [hidden link](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/hidden-links/), which can really throw a user for a loop.

A tooltip is often used to specify extra information about something when the user moves the mouse pointer over an element. Their intention isn't to indicate a link. Using this to demonstrate something is clickable isn't apparent just via a glance, and the hover method doesn't exist for mobile or tablet devices.

What you must remember is that an interactive object should **look** that way. If this is something you struggle with, try a CSS boilerplate like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). They do all this kind of thinking for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're dismissive of your option Grey-Out inactive elements.

It is universal UI-pattern that disabled items are grayed out. If you find the UI is noisy with these elements, consider altering their state until enabled.

For example, if an entire panel is disabled that contains many buttons, text, and media. Consider desaturations, blurs, or create a clear textual indication that the whole panel is not available.

Don't forget to tell the user what they need to do in order to activate the panel.

^ If you explore this than your concern is not how to make GUI look active, but how to manage inactive elements.

^ If you continue to explore how to make active elements looks active you'll be in for a world of hurt, as this is not a known UI-Pattern by anyone. All interactive UI elements are active until clearly said otherwise.

### Remember! Don't Make the user think.

Comment: "List surprise principle", "keep it simple" are indeed important. Having said that, greying out text  in all non-interactive parts of the program would make it look murky. As for checkboxes/sliders - greying out works well. Inactive buttons can often be hidden. What to do with HTML like text where some words can be clickable?